# How to install extensions using docker-php-extension-installer

Tags: php, dockerfile

I'm new to docker.
I would like to use docker-php-extension-installer for installing PHP extensions to my container, because according to php-docker hub docs this script builds upon the docker-php-ext-* scripts and simplifies the installation of PHP extensions by automatically adding and removing Debian (apt) and Alpine (apk) packages.

The problem is when I try to install gd or pdo_mysql or something else, extensions are installed but not shown in the modules list when I run php -m command in my bash.

Here is my DockerFile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Use the default production configuration
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip \
    && apt-get install -y git nano \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# use https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer to simply install php extensions with dependencies
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/master/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions gd pdo_mysql
```

Maybe I have to enable these extensions somehow, but how can I do it from my Dockerfile? There is nothing said about this neither in docker-php-extension-installer page docs, no in official php docker page.

If anybody knows, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you did rebuild your image? When I use the info from [their doc](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer#downloading-the-script-on-the-fly) and I throw an extra `pdo_mysql`, and then end my `Dockerfile` with `CMD php -m` I do see the expected modules listed there

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The above-mentioned Dockerfile is used as part of docker-compose. When I created a docker-compose.yml file, I made a mistake. To change default php configuration, I mounted host folded, where I keep my custom php.ini, and mapped it to conf.d folder in php container. Like this:

```
  # PHP Service
  php:
    build: ./.docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/php/conf.d:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d:ro
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

But the conf.d folder keeps the configuration of all installed extensions, for example:

```
docker-php-ext-gd.ini  docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini  docker-php-ext-sodium.ini  docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

So the contents of my host folder replaced the original conf.d contents and as a result - extensions didn't work.